# checking if a span tag is inside of a link

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I'm trying to get all spans with the class "blah2" that are not children of links.  For example, I want both of these guys:

```
<a href="nowhere.com"><span class="blah1"><span class="blah2"></span></span></a>
<a href="nowhere.com"><span class="blah2"></span></a>
```

I tried:

```
$('.blah2').each(function(locator_id){
    if (!$(this).parent().attr("href")){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

The problem is that this only works in the second case above.  Is there anyway to check for this even if the link might not be the immediate parent?

Comment: have you tried .parents() instead of .parent()?

Comment: You state a contradiction.  You say you want the `.blah2` that are not children of links, but in your example you say you want the ones that are descendants of a link, including one that is a child.  Precisely what do you need?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity: I need to do one thing if the .blah2 class is "inside" of a link, and something else if it's not.

Comment: Adil's seemed to work for me; could they both be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). You can do something like:

```
if ($(this).closest('a').length === 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of .closest()

Answer (score 1):

Use `parents()` instead of `parent()` to get all the parents above the hierarchy tree.

```
$('.blah2').each(function(locator_id){
       if (!$(this).parents('a').length){
            //do stuff
       } else {
            //don't do stuff

       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if($(this).parent().is('a'))
    // do stuff
```

**Update**
I did not take into account that a `span` may not be a direct descendant.

```
if($('.span').closest('a').length !== 0)
    // do stuff
```

Comment: I don't believe that would work for the first example because the parent for `.blah2` there is `span.blah1`.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock That is true.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of listing span `$('.blah2')` then check it's parent, change your selector into something like this `$('a .blah2')` to be sure that all `<span>` are actually inside `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/WfL78/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.blah2').parents().attr("href")){
        alert('I have href parent tags');
    } else {
        alert('I do not have href parent tags');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I will used this

> $('a .blah2').length //Error

Sorry with `$('.blah2').length - $('a ~ .blah2').length`

example http://jsbin.com/emitoj/7/edit

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a recursive function that check each parent node: http://jsfiddle.net/TUUba/

```
function insideLink(el) {
    if(el.parentElement != null) {
        if(el.parentElement.nodeName == "A") {
            return true;
        }
        // Call the function checking the parent element
        return arguments.callee(el.parentElement);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
$('.blah2').each(function(locator_id) {
    alert("insideLink: " + insideLink(this));
});
```

Comment: The question is tagged 'jQuery' so, no, the OP doesn't have to go to the trouble to do all that.

Comment: The main post was tagged as jQuery but he didn't say that we have to send a response using only jQuery functions. My code It's more instructive...